# Add text to XML child element using XSL while preserving all children and attributes of children

Tags: xml, xslt, docbook

I'm trying to add some text to a paragraph based on the 'performance' attribute of it's 'step' parent.

If a step is marked 'performance="optional"' I would like the resulting text (for the second step below) to look like this:

"2. (Optional) This is step 2..."

```
<procedure>
    <step id="step_lkq_c1l_5j">
        <para>This is step 1, which is required.</para>
    </step>
    <step performance="optional">
        <para>This is step 2, which is optional, unlike <xref linkend="step_lkq_c1l_5j"/>.
            <note>
                <para>I don't want to lose this note in my transformation.</para>
            </note>
        </para>
    </step>
    <step>
        <para>This is step 3.</para>
    </step>
</procedure>
```

I tried using Xpath to match my node and modify it: `<xsl:template match="step[@performance='optional']/child::para[position()=1]">` and then using concat() to attempt to prepend my Optional text, but I would lose the xref link (possibly because concat() doesn't respect children and attributes?)

I've gotten sort of close to what I want using the following xsl customization, but the (Optional) text sits outside the paragraph and this drops the step text down a line and sometimes breaks with page content. What I really want is the genereated text to be inside the first paragraph.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

```
    <!-- Add "(Optional) " to steps that have the performance="optional" attribute set -->
<xsl:template match="procedure/step|substeps/step">
    <xsl:variable name="id">
        <xsl:call-template name="object.id"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="keep.together">
        <xsl:call-template name="pi.dbfo_keep-together"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <fo:list-item xsl:use-attribute-sets="list.item.spacing">
        <xsl:if test="$keep.together != ''">
            <xsl:attribute name="keep-together.within-column"><xsl:value-of
                select="$keep.together"/></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>

        <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
            <fo:block id="{$id}">
                <!-- dwc: fix for one step procedures. Use a bullet if there's no step 2 -->
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="count(../step) = 1">
                        <xsl:text>&#x2022;</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="number">
                            <xsl:with-param name="recursive" select="0"/>
                        </xsl:apply-templates>.
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:list-item-label>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@performance='optional'">
                <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
                    <fo:block>
                        <xsl:text>(Optional) </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:list-item-body>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
                    <fo:block>
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:list-item-body>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </fo:list-item>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Do you have a template that matches your `para` elements?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question whether you simply want to know how to add the "(Optional)" text, or whether you want it incorporated into your XSL-FO, or whether you want the "2." numbering as well. Here's a simple answer for the first case:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="step[@performance = 'optional']/para/text()[1]">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('(Optional) ', normalize-space())"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, this produces:

```
<procedure>
  <step id="step_lkq_c1l_5j">
    <para>This is step 1, which is required.</para>
  </step>
  <step performance="optional">
    <para>(Optional) This is step 2, which is optional, unlike<xref linkend="step_lkq_c1l_5j" />.
      <note><para>I don't want to lose this note in my transformation.</para></note></para>
  </step>
  <step>
    <para>This is step 3.</para>
  </step>
</procedure>
```

To get the numbering, you can replace that second template with this:

```
  <xsl:template match="step[@performance = 'optional']/para/text()[1]">
    <xsl:variable name="sequence">
      <xsl:number level="multiple" count="step"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($sequence, '. (Optional) ', normalize-space())"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Which produces:

```
<procedure>
  <step id="step_lkq_c1l_5j">
    <para>This is step 1, which is required.</para>
  </step>
  <step performance="optional">
    <para>2. (Optional) This is step 2, which is optional, unlike<xref linkend="step_lkq_c1l_5j" />.
      <note><para>I don't want to lose this note in my transformation.</para></note></para>
  </step>
  <step>
    <para>This is step 3.</para>
  </step>
</procedure>
```

And to number all steps, you can replace that same template with this:

```
  <xsl:template match="step/para/text()[1]">
    <xsl:variable name="sequence">
      <xsl:number level="multiple" count="step"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($sequence, '. ')"/>

    <xsl:if test="../../@performance = 'optional'">
      <xsl:text>(Optional) </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Which produces:

```
<procedure>
  <step id="step_lkq_c1l_5j">
    <para>1. This is step 1, which is required.</para>
  </step>
  <step performance="optional">
    <para>2. (Optional) This is step 2, which is optional, unlike<xref linkend="step_lkq_c1l_5j" />.
      <note><para>I don't want to lose this note in my transformation.</para></note></para>
  </step>
  <step>
    <para>3. This is step 3.</para>
  </step>
</procedure>
```